# mysql workbench auto dump

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to make mysql workbench dump automaticly the data?
I know how to dump it manually but I'm sure there is a way to dump it automatically.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, MySQL workbench doesn't have a job scheduler.  A typical MySQL auto dump is done by have a batch script with the `mysqldump` code and using either cron job on UNIX side or Windows Scheduler to execute the script.

Comment: do I have to use Windows Scheduler with mysql Command line client? Is there a way to make Windows Scheduler work with Mysql Workbench?

Comment: In windows rename your  script filename.bat.  This makes the script executable with Windows Scheduler.